# JQuery/JavaScript - Timing problems

Tags: javascript, jquery, timing

I created a class that I tried to instanciate in order to see if it was handling the way I wanted, and it works fine.

Actually, not as fine as I'd like to, `check[i].id()` will only appear in console when I pause the console at the `each` loop.

Otherwise, nothing will show off and `check` will be `undefined`. I don't really understand where the problem lies, this is the first time I encounter this timing issue. I wondered if the problem came from my AJAX request being too slow, but isn't it supposed to wait for calculation before filling `check` var?

Here is the code, I modified it a bit for clarity:

```js
var Form = function(formSelector, buttonsSelector) {
  var id;

  return {
    // Index of specific form
    setId: function(val) {
      (!isNaN(val)) ? id = val: console.log('Id must be integer')
    },
    id: function() {
      return id
    },

    // Get selectors
    formSelector: function() {
      return formSelector
    },
    buttonsSelector: function() {
      return buttonsSelector
    },

    // Get all DOM elements
    getAll: function() {
      return $(formSelector)
    },

    // Get id related elements
    get: function() {
      return $(this.getAll()).get(id)
    },
    buttons: function() {
      var buttons = $(this.get()).find(buttonsSelector);
      var elements = [];

      var proceed = $.ajax({
        url: 'myURL.php',
        dataType: 'json'
      }).done(function(data) {
        $(buttons).each(function(i) {
          if ((data.id()).includes($(buttons[i]).attr('id'))) {
            var element = new Buttons($(buttons[i]), data[i].id);

            elements.push(element);
          }
        });

        return true;
      });

      if (proceed) return elements;
    }
  }
}

$(function() {
  var test = new Form('.whatever', '.whatever2');
  var check = test.buttons();

  $(check).each(function(i) {
    console.log(check[i].id());
  });
});
```

Thanks!

Comment: Edited some errors after code modification

Comment: you return the elemnts BEFORE ajax is complete. try accepting a callback and calling it with the elemnts when ajax completes (ie inside `done`)

Comment: or even return a promise (from `buttons` method) and use `async/await` in order to process them afterwards

Comment: @NikosM. Thank you for your answers. Though, how can I know when ajax is complete inside `done`? I tried adding `complete: function () { return elements }` to my AJAX request, but it still won't work

Comment: you need to accept a callback function in `buttons` method and then CALL this callback on `done` or `complete` and pass it the elements as well. NOT JUST return the elements this wont work, noone is there to acceot them

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For example accept a callback in your `buttons` method like below

```
//.. rest class as is, only buttons method cahnges
buttons: function(callback) {
  var buttons = $(this.get()).find(buttonsSelector);
  var elements = [];

  var proceed = $.ajax({
    url: 'myURL.php',
    dataType: 'json'
  }).done(function(data) {
    $(buttons).each(function(i) {
      if ((data.id()).includes($(buttons[i]).attr('id'))) {
        var element = new Buttons($(buttons[i]), data[i].id);

        elements.push(element);
      }
    });

    if (callback) callback(elements);
    return true;
  });
}
```

Then you can do:

```
$(function() {
  var test = new Form('.whatever', '.whatever2');
  test.buttons(function(elements){
     $(elements).each(function(i) {
       console.log(elements[i].id());
     });
});
```

});

The ajax call (and many other processes in javascript) is **asynchronous**, meaning that is started at a certain time and ends in another time, while execution **DOES NOT** pause waiting for it to finish before proceding to the next statement in the program flow.

This happens for a number of reasons, for example the process needs to query some resources which are not available immediately and so on. So there is some delay in starting the process and having the results back.

In order to **NOT BLOCK** the current thread of execution while waiting, the process becomes *asynchronous* and the execution continues (that is why `return` does not wait to load the results but returns empty array).

So a way is needed to *call-back* the caller with the results when ready. For this reason [callbacks and/or promises](https://medium.com/codebuddies/getting-to-know-asynchronous-javascript-callbacks-promises-and-async-await-17e0673281ee) are used to handle this type of asynhronous programming. The callback **DOES NOT** pause execution like you might think, instead it is called when results are ready so the original caller is called through the callback function with the results passed as arguments. Take a toor of asynhronous javascript, callbacks and promises to get an idea of what it means and how to use them (see link above).

Comment: Alright I see now what I did wrong, thank you for you time, good sir

Comment: @Snite, if this solves your problem please accept the answer. On stackoverflow there are people trying to help but deserve at least recogntion

Comment: Done. It works well. Though I would like to know why a callback function like this one will wait for the previous code to execute and not the "return elements" inside the done() function. Why doesn't it wait for the loop to run first before returning anything? Why does a function do wait for it to run?

Comment: @Snite, the ajax call is asynchronous that means that it is executed now and the result is ready some time after (but execution DOES NOT pause waiting to finish), while return happens immediately. So a way is needed to call-back the caller with the results when it is finished. This is why asynchronous programming uses callbacks and/or promises because execution DOES NOT pause, and a way is needed to pass results back when finished

Comment: @Snite, updated my answer with some explanation of asynhronous programming and links for further study